# Update records based on inserted IDs and another non source column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, sql-insert, insert-update

Probably there is already answer for it, but i couldn't find it... So i have 2 tables and data in third one. Lets name them (Source, Target and UpdateTarget).

I need to insert records from Source to Target, then grab autoincremented IDs from Target and update UpdateTarget table with these IDs based on filters from Source table. I've tried to use OUTPUT, but it gives me an error:

> The multi-part identifier "s.EmployeeID" could not be bound.

Here is my current SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.target
(
    id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    employee VARCHAR(32)
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.source
(
    id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    employee VARCHAR(32),
    EmployeeID int
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.updateTarget
(
    id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    ExternalID int
);

DECLARE @MyTableVar TABLE
(
    id INT,
    EmployeeID int
);

    INSERT dbo.target (employee)
    OUTPUT 
        inserted.id, -- autoincremented ID
        s.EmployeeID -- here i got an error
        INTO @MyTableVar
    SELECT s.employee
    FROM dbo.source AS s

    UPDATE dbo.updateTarget
    SET ExternalID = data.ID
    FROM @MyTableVar data
    WHERE updateTarget.ID = data.EmployeeID


DROP TABLE source
DROP TABLE target
DROP TABLE updateTarget
```

I don't have EmployeeID column in target table.

Is there a way to achieve it without making two queries for each record? Or can you point me to existing answer if there are any?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) INSERT INTO table variable generated id, and EmployeeId for usage in update

2) MERGE instead of INSERT (it allows to get column EmployeeId from SRC)

3) OUTPUT result, action inserted, getting id from TGT and EmployeeId

```
INSERT INTO @MyTableVar(id, EmployeeId)
SELECT id, EmployeeId 
FROM (
    MERGE dbo.target TGT
    USING dbo.source SRC
    ON TGT.employee = SRC.employee
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
       INSERT (employee)
       VALUES (src.employee)
    OUTPUT inserted.id, SRC.EmployeeId)
AS out(id, EmployeeId);;
```

[MERGE gives better OUTPUT options](http://blogs.lobsterpot.com.au/2012/06/12/merge-gives-better-output-options/)

Comment: Amazing! you very helped me. Thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome. Remember CTE and MERGE is "Swiss army knife" for TSQL :)